# Redux reducer initial state issues

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a reducer that set the state for a redux-form, and also for a display-only page (not a form)...

```
import { LOAD_USER_SUCCESS, LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = { data: [] }

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {  
  switch(action.type) {
    case LOAD_USER_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, data: action.data };
    case LOAD_USERS_SUCCESS:
      console.log('LOAD_USER_SUCCESS');
      return { ...state, data: action.data };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

You can see above that I set an initial state, and I do this because otherwise the display-only page throws error before the fetch is complete:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (thrown at 'this.props.users' below)...

```
class Users extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadUsers();
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <PageWrapper>
          <table className="w-full text-left table-collapse">
            <thead>
              <tr className="text-sm text-grey-darker bg-grey-lightest">
                <TableTH name="Name" />
                <TableTH name="Email" />
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
             {this.props.users.map((user, i) => (
                <UserListItem firstName={user.profile.firstName} lastName={user.profile.lastName} email={user.email} key={i} />
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </PageWrapper>
    );
  }
}

function TableTH(props) {
    return (
        <th className="p-2">{props.name}</th>
    )
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {  
  if(state.user.data) {
    return { users: state.user.data }
  } else {
    return {};
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loadUsers })(Users);
```

But the redux-form populates with that same initial state (no content), and doesn't update when fetch is complete since it's immutable.

If I remove the INITIAL state in the reducer, the redux-form populates perfectly but I get the 'map' error mentioned above.

Here's the form:

```
let UserForm = props => {

  const { handleSubmit, onSubmit } = props;

    return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

            <FormItem
                label = { <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label> }
                field = { <Field name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First name" component="input" className="w-full"/>} 
            />

            <FormItem
                label = { <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label> }
                field = { <Field name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last name" component="input" className="w-full"/> }
            />

            <FormItem
                label = { <label htmlFor="email">Email</label> }
                field = { <Field name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" component="input" className="w-full"/>}
            />

            <FormFooter
                left={ <Button href="/users" icon="fa-ban" text="Cancel" /> }
                right={ <button type="submit">Save</button> }
            />

        </form>
    )
}

UserForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'userForm'
})(UserForm)

function mapStateToProps(state) {  
  return { initialValues: state.user.data }
}

UserForm = connect(mapStateToProps
)(UserForm)

export default UserForm
```

Here's where I create the store:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

registerServiceWorker();
```

Here's the main reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';  
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';  
import authReducer from './auth_reducer';
import userReducer from './user_reducer';
import calendarReducer from './calendar_reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({  
  auth: authReducer,
  form: formReducer,
  user: userReducer,
  calendar: calendarReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

How should I change this to satisfy both pages?

Comment: Please show place where you assign reducer to the store. Do you use `combineReducers`? Check output of state in `mapStateToProps` and you will get answer what is wrong.

Comment: @AndrzejDybionka Updated

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to set the `INITIAL_STATE` as `{}`, and then in your component, don't render rows when there is no user:

```
class Users extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadUsers();
  }

  render() {
    const userRows = this.props.users ? 
      (
        <tbody>
          {this.props.users.map((user, i) => (
            <UserListItem firstName={user.profile.firstName} lastName={user.profile.lastName} email={user.email} key={i} />
           ))}
        </tbody>
      ) : null

    return (
      <PageWrapper>
          <table className="w-full text-left table-collapse">
            <thead>
              <tr className="text-sm text-grey-darker bg-grey-lightest">
                <TableTH name="Name" />
                <TableTH name="Email" />
              </tr>
            </thead>

           {userRows}
          </table>
      </PageWrapper>
    );
  }
}

function TableTH(props) {
    return (
        <th className="p-2">{props.name}</th>
    )
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {  
  if(state.user.data) {
    return { users: state.user.data }
  } else {
    return {};
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loadUsers })(Users);
```

Another approach would be to keep your `INITIAL_STATE` the way it currently is, and ensure that there is always an iterable `users` key in your `Users` `props`. You could modify the `mapStateToProps` to be something like:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {  
  return { users: state.user.data ? state.user.data : [] };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, that works, but I hesitated to do that as it seemed smelly. Is that best practice?

Comment: @99miles, so I think it's a form of [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html). If you want it to be "cleaner", then I think you'd have to refactor into (possibly) more components. The root of your `TypeError` is that you're assuming `this.props.users` exists in `props`, but it may not depending on state / `INITIAL_STATE`...so you have to account for that somehow.

Comment: Another approach (perhaps less smelly?) is to change your `Users` `mapStateToProps` so that there is always an iterable `users` key in `props`. For example, return `{users: state.user.data ? state.user.data : []}`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide the entire code I can give you three tips:

1. You should pass `initialValues` as object not array. So your initial state of user reducer should be `const INITIAL_STATE = { data: {} }`
2. You mentioned something about immutable. I don't see how you import redux-form but since your Redux state is not an immutable object, you should not import redux-form from `redux-form/immutable` but just from `redux-form`.
3. `rootReducer` has not redux-form reducer.

Reducer should look like this:

```
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({  
  auth: authReducer,
  user: userReducer,
  form: formReducer
});
```

Comment: I tried your #1 above, that didn't help. I already had redux-form, I accidentally omitted it when slimming down code for this post. I'm updating original post with the full reducer code.